# Pymongo how to see if document already exists with multiple keys

Tags: python, pymongo

I am having trouble seeing if multiple keys within a document align with what the user gives. The user has the ability to create documents in pymongo but if a document with the same key, value already exists then I want it to update the existing document instead.

This is my code for adding new items:

```py
async def create_new_shop(user_id, amount, price, item):
    await python_bot.insert_one({"_id": user_id, "item": item, "price": price, "amount": amount})
```

This is my code for checking if it already exists(I only want the _id and item):

```py
async def check_item_exists(user_id, item):
    check = python_bot.find_one({'$and': [{"_id": user_id},
                                          {"item": item}]})
    print(check)
    return check is not None
```

Whenever printing check I get:

```
<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/futures.py:384]>
```

Any help is appreciated. If you need more information I can provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `update_one` method with `upsert=True` option enabled.

```
thon_bot.update_one({
     "_id": user_id,
}, {
     "$set": {
          "item": item, 
          "price": price, 
          "amount": amount
     }
}, upsert=True)
```

This will update based on the `user_id` value passed, inserts if the document doesn't exist.